# how to toggle between two ids rather than classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way to `toggle` the styles of `IDs` in `jQuery`, the same way that `toggleClass();` function do but with `IDs` and not `classes`.

this what is i tried with toggling `classes` and it works fine.
any solution with `IDs`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".header-container").toggleClass("closed");
   });
}):
```

i know that in such situations i should use `classes` but for flexibility and in some cases we have `IDs` . any suggestions

Comment: Not sure that i understand you correctly... You can use id selector, too?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `$("#header-container").toggleClass("closed");` instead? That has nothing to do with toggleClass specifically then ...

Comment: what i intend to do is assume i have two styles with IDs #closed and #open and need to toggle between them

Comment: @samehanwar Do you mean `#closed` became `#open` and vice versa or just change `#closed` id to `open`?! Anyway, whatever you are trying to do doesn't seem the right way. BTW, providing snippet would make your issue clearer for sure

Comment: yes , toggling between them like toggleClass()

Comment: Guess you should just do it manually

Comment: Maybe it is what you are looking for BUT it really doesn't make sense to use it: https://jsfiddle.net/faewpo66/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no function for toggling classes in jquery . you define one 
create a new plugin to toggle between two functions

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.fn.idToggle = function(a,b) {
        function cb(){ [b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this); }
        return this.on("click", cb);
     };
        
     $('button').idToggle(
         function(){
           $('.header-container').attr('id','closed');
          },
         function(){
           $('.header-container').attr('id','open');
      });
});
```

```css
.header-container { padding : 40px;}
#open{ background:#f08;}
#closed { background:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-container" id="open">
    <div class="menu"> </div>
</div>
<button> click btn </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can edit the `attrubite` using  [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) :

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".header-container").toggleClass("closed");
      if($(".header-container").attr('id')=='opened'){
      $(".header-container").attr('id','closed');
      }else{
       $(".header-container").attr('id','opened');
      }
      var elid = $(".header-container").attr('id');
      $(".header-container").html("i got an id now :"+elid);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-container">My id is empty</div>
<button>Edite Id</button>
```